# Issues with fputs

Tags: c

I'm doing and small exercise where I choose a file and I want the content of the file in reverse, I got problems in the last loop, this is the error I got **Process returned -1073741819 (0xC0000005)   execution time : 5.427 s**

Example:

File1:

```
 Line1
 Line2
 Line3
```

File2:

```
 Line3
 Line2
 Line1
```

This is my code

```
#define MAXCHAR 1000
int main()
{
    FILE *fptr1, *fptr2;
    char filename[MAXCHAR];
    int i=0;
    char *lines[4];

    printf("Enter the filename to open for reading \n");
    scanf("%s", filename);

    fptr1 = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (fptr1 == NULL){
        printf("Cannot open file %s \n", filename);
        exit(0);
    }

    for(i=0;fgets(filename, MAXCHAR, fptr1) != NULL; i++){
        lines[i] = filename;
        //printf("%s", lines[i]);
    }

    //FILE 2
    printf("\n Enter the filename to open for writing \n");
    scanf("%s", filename);

    fptr2 = fopen(filename, "w");
    if (fptr2 == NULL)
    {
        printf("Cannot open file %s \n", filename);
        exit(0);
    }

    for(i = 4; i > 0;i--){
        fputs(lines[i],fptr2);
    }


    fclose(fptr1);
    fclose(fptr2);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `lines[i] = filename;` You are assigning the same value each time. You can use [`strdup`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/experimental/dynamic/strdup) instead.

Comment: `for(i = 4; i > 0;i--){` 4 is not a valid index. Use `for(i = 3; i >= 0;i--){`

Comment: @JohnnyMopp I printed and was working well lines[i] = filename; so I dont think this is the problem

Comment: @Lluis `lines[i] = filename` is not _the_ problem, but it definitely is a problem.

Comment: Okey, and why it's a problem? I changed anyways to strdup

Comment: Assume the address of `filename = 0x123`. Then you will end up with `lines[0] = 0x123; lines[1] = 0x123; lines[2] = 0x123; etc....` They all point to the same memory location.

Comment: @Lluis because it does not work. Try the corrected program (without strdup) and look what file2 looks like....

Comment: @Lluis and BTW you program won't work with files that have not exactly 4 lines.

Comment: Solved, the error was on char *lines[4]; Need to be char *lines[4][max];